# SQL Concat and Join 3 Tables Only Return Records Matching Criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables with the structure listed below.

```
user [user_id | firstname | lastname ]
user_messages [user_message_id | from_user_id | etc ]
user_messages_user_status [user_message_id | user_id | etc ]
```

What I am trying to do is return the results like:

```
results [user_id | user_message_id | from_user_full_name | to_user_full_name]
```

This is what I have so far, but I keep getting an error near 'CONCAT_WS:

```
SELECT *,
   CONCAT_WS(' ', fu.firstname, fu.lastname) fun
   CONCAT_WS(' ', tu.firstname, tu.lastname) tun
FROM user_messages um
   LEFT JOIN user_messages_user_status umus
     ON um.user_message_id = umus.user_message_id
   INNER JOIN user fu
     ON um.from_user_id = fu.user_id
   INNER JOIN user tu
     ON umus.user_id = tu.user_id
WHERE um.user_id = 'number' OR fun LIKE 'Name%' OR tun LIKE 'Name%'
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: could you at least spend 1 minute debugging before asking?

Comment: @Vland Missing commas are sometimes hard to find, and at least the OP included a complete question, what they tried, and the error they were getting. Can't really ask for too much more here IMHO.

Comment: Stick your commas at the beginning of the line and you can never miss them!

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a comma in your select list, between the `fun` alias and the `CONCAT_WS` call for the next column:

```
SELECT *,
   CONCAT_WS(' ', fu.firstname, fu.lastname) fun,
--                                             ^^^
   CONCAT_WS(' ', tu.firstname, tu.lastname) tun
FROM user_messages um
   LEFT JOIN user_messages_user_status umus
     ON um.user_message_id = umus.user_message_id
   INNER JOIN user fu
     ON um.from_user_id = fu.user_id
   INNER JOIN user tu
     ON umus.user_id = tu.user_id
WHERE um.user_id = 'number' OR fun LIKE 'Name%' OR tun LIKE 'Name%'
```

---

However you will not be able to use a `WHERE` query on your derived columns `fun` and `tun` simply by specifying their aliases. You can either specify the `CONCAT_WS` function again - `WHERE CONCAT_WS(' ', fu.firstname, fu.lastname) LIKE 'Name%'` - or come up with a different way of searching - `WHERE fu.firstname LIKE 'FName%' AND fu.lastname LIKE 'LName%'`. Note that by using the function here the database engine will most likely not be able to take advantage of indexes.

I trust you can handle specifying the columns you need instead of the `*`.

Comment: Ah yes that was a silly typo. Now I can get it to return the results how I would like, but I still can not search on the "fun" or "tun" columns.

Comment: Or do I need to use concat again in the where clause?